# Android navigation without GPS and WIFI

Tags: android, localization

I would like to make an app which is keep tracking various points in a room in 3D and can tell where to look up the tracked points again.

The problem is: **I can't use GPS and Wifi points** to determine my phone's location and orientation.

So far I know two things which can be useful in this case, the gravitation force, and magnetic north. It is not a problem if there is some misleading fake magnetic north unless it is too close to the room where I want to locate things.

I found that the gyro + acceleration isn't accurate enough to use, is there a "ready made" API what I can use for that? I have the feeling I am reinventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use navigation from Network Provider rather than Gps Provider. Network Provider not gives the actual but almost correct lat lang.

Comment: @HarshitRathi Is network provider good enough to tell few inch movement with the phone? Sadly I cannot assume the user has wifi connection or wifi spots around them.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary did you found anything useful as i am in the same situation you were last year. Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Salmaan Sadly whatever we found were more or less inaccurate. We found that only two parameters were good enough to use: gravity and north. Sadly these things define only the direction of the device, it is not enough. I can't recommend anything since the most inaccurate thing in here is the motion sensor, for a limit it is ok, but not precise enough to navigate in a room for example. These are dead ends with the available toolset.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one "ready made" API - Fused locations ( https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html ). But currently it relies on GPS/WiFi/Cell-tower data. I don't beleive there is easy/cheap solution for your problem.

You could use bunch of Bluetooth devices, maybe some BT4 low power tags. Place them everywhere in the room and measure signal strength of each.

Comment: If you want to use only sensors search for "Inertial navigation system".

Comment: it seems I have no other choice than inertial navigation system. I am waiting maybe somebody knows any help on that. Sadly bluetooth accessories are out of question, I have limitation to a single app which has to solve the problem with it's very own resources.

Comment: Our conclusion was the same, but we never made the project, I leave the question opened, if somebody has any other idea, otherwise I would accept your answer.